# How to ask turtles to import values for a csv.file in NETLOGO

Tags: csv, netlogo

I have created turtles using this procedure

```
file-open "C:/Users/.../netlogo.csv"
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
   let data csv:from-row file-read-line
   create-turtles 1 [
     set size 0.1
     setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
     set codcatasto item 0 data
     set set yExp item 1 data
         ]
 ]
```

Now I want to to ask turtles to change yExp every tick, importing data from another csv.file. I cannot replicate the same procedure substituting "create turtles" with "ask turtles" because the order of turtles is random and there is not a correspondence between the turtles "0" and the first line of my file. 
So, I have tried this

```
enter code here
```

`file-open file-open "C:/Users/.../netlogo2.csv"
while [ not file-at-end? ] [
let data csv:from-row file-read-line
  foreach sort-on [who] turtles  [ ask ?[
        set yExp item 2 data
      ]
]`

But it does not work. Turtles are sorted now, but for each of them I get the value of the last row of my file.

Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a folder called 'data' that stores my input files. For example, I have an inital values file called "initialvals.csv" that looks like:

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
D,4
E,5
```

And I have 'vals1.csv', 'vals2.csv', and 'vals3.csv' to store my `yExp` values that just contain values 1:5 multiplied by 10, 100, and 1000 respectively.

So, to import this in an ordered way:

```
extensions [ csv ]

turtles-own [ codcatasto yExp ]

to setup
  ca 
  crt 5 [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
  ]
  let input csv:from-file "data/initialvals.csv"
  ( foreach ( sort turtles ) input [
    [ t dpair ] ->
    ask t [
      set codcatasto first dpair
      set yExp last dpair
    ]
  ] )
  reset-ticks
end
```

Now, you can do more or less the same thing, but with the 'vals' csv files. In this example, I've set them up to be tied to the current `ticks` value, so that each tick the file accessed is different:

```
to go
  let newfile ( word "data/vals" ( ticks + 1 ) ".csv" )
  let newinput csv:from-file newfile
  ( foreach ( sort turtles ) newinput [
    [ t datum ] ->
    ask t [
      set yExp datum 
      show ( word codcatasto " " yExp )
    ]
  ] )
  tick
end
```

After tick 0:

```
(turtle 0): "A [10]"
(turtle 1): "B [20]"
(turtle 2): "C [30]"
(turtle 3): "D [40]"
(turtle 4): "E [50]"
```

After tick 1:

```
(turtle 0): "A [100]"
(turtle 1): "B [200]"
(turtle 2): "C [300]"
(turtle 3): "D [400]"
(turtle 4): "E [500]"
```

After tick 2:

```
(turtle 0): "A [1000]"
(turtle 1): "B [2000]"
(turtle 2): "C [3000]"
(turtle 3): "D [4000]"
(turtle 4): "E [5000]"
```

Obviously, if you have more ticks than input files this will stop working.

Comment: Thank you Luke! It was what I was looking for.